# Question on Salesforce License Management App (LMA)?

Tags: lma

I want to know the implications of moving a managed package that was done as a custom development into a managed package where the licenses are tracked in the LMA.

As my client already have `licence and managed package` is already installed in the org, Now we need to upgrade it through app exchange and track the license.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure as to what you're asking for, but I will share my experience with LMA.

If you create a managed package and use the LMA, **any previous existing installations of your package will not show in the LMA.**

Only when your customers upgrade the package will they appear listed in the LMA. Any new installs will appear in the LMA automatically as well.

I would definitely use the LMA. We use it regularly to debug issues and connect to our customers' orgs (provided they give us access), and it's the *only way* I know of to see the debug logs from your managed package.

Hope it helped. Good luck!

Comment: I am new to the LMA, how do use it to connect to your customers' orgs and see the debug logs from your managed package? We are considering implementing it ourselves but the currently features don't seem too helpful to our business needs; however, if could allow us to see debug logs it would be completely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link helps you [enter link description here][1]https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout